# Locate an element in an image resized in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pyautogui

I'm create a project in Python using PyAutogui and I need to locate an object on the screen. First of all I crop a screenshot, and after that, I use `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('element.png')` for found the location. The problem is, the element sometimes is resized so this method can't found it. I tried use `confidence` but not work properly with that. How can i locate that element using pyautogui or something different?
This is my code:

```
png = ["Andrew","David","Emma","Jay","Jesse","Josh","Mickey"]
screen = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x+1,y+1,1281,751))

for element in png:
    if(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(element + '.png',confidence=0.7) != None):
        print("Find " + element)
```

Comment: Maybe, taking a screenshot every time you need to click that thing. Could you be more elaborate?

Comment: I've edited the question adding the code, takiing a screenshot could be tedius for the computer because i need to locate these objects in different views. Simply locateOnScreen doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: You could try resizing the image yourself if it's not found

Comment: That's not possible because i don't know the exact resize of the images, i'm trying now some solution based on OpenCV for detection image

Comment: Okay, well good luck. And make sure to post the answer in here when you find it